# jquery level two slides up and level three slides down

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slidetoggle

Hopefully this is a small one.

I have a three level vertical menu. It is built in wordpress and I am attempting to keep it simple before I start putting in content and such.

I have got the sub menus to hide and when you click a level 1 button, the level 2 menu will slide down or slide shut (slideToggle). My issue is when you click a third level, the second level (parent) slides up and the third level slides down at the same time. When you click the second level again, it shows the second and third as it is still open.

I have added console.log to check what is happening and it shows the following:
enter down
down
exit down
enter up
up
exit up

So from what I see, it is entering the slide down, sliding it down and leaving. It then enters the slide up, slides up and then exits. It's confusing as it is an if else. How can it do both???

I have dropped it in codepen if anyone is interested. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJeevd

(Click Button 3 and then Click Button 3.4 to see third level effect)
Any ideas muchly appreciated.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-header">

<li id="menu-item-192" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-192"><a>Button 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="">Button 1.1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="">Button 1.2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-158"><a>Button 2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-159"><a href="">Button 2.1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-160"><a href="">Button 2.2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-202" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-202"><a>Button 3</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="">Button 3.1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-206" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-206"><a href="">Button 3.2</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-205" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-205"><a href="">Button 3.3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-207" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-207"><a>Button 3.4</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-204"><a href="">Button 3.4.1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-203"><a href="">Button 3.4.2</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
</ul>

</li>

<li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="">Button 4</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103"><a href="">Button 5</a></li>

</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").click( function(event) {
var target = $(this).find('> .sub-menu');
if(target.is(':visible')) {
console.log('enter up');
target.slideUp(500);
console.log('up');
console.log('exit up');
} else {
console.log('enter down');
target.slideDown(500);
console.log('down');
console.log('exit down');
}

});
```

CSS

```
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.menu-item-has-children` class is assigned to `<li>`. Which means the `.sub-menu` inside that particular `<li>` is contained in it and when you click the "button 3.4", both `<li>`'s i.e. "Button 3.4" and "Button 3" are triggered which causes that effect. Not sure if I explained it clearly.

One solution would be to assign `.menu-item-has-children` to `<a>` and then `find` its parent element's `.sub-menu`, like the snippet below.

```js
 $(".menu-item-has-children").click( function(event) {
     
     var target = $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu');
       
  if(target.is(':visible')) {
      
   console.log('enter up');
   
   target.slideUp(500);
    
      
   console.log('exit up');

  } else {
      
   console.log('enter down');
   
   target.slideDown(500);
    
  
    
   console.log('exit down');
   
  }
     
 });
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-header">
 
 <li id="menu-item-192" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-192"><a class="menu-item-has-children">Button 1</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="">Button 1.1</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="">Button 1.2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 
 <li id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-158"><a class="menu-item-has-children">Button 2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-159"><a href="">Button 2.1</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-160"><a href="">Button 2.2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 
 <li id="menu-item-202" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-202"><a class="menu-item-has-children">Button 3</a>
  
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="">Button 3.1</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-206" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-206"><a href="">Button 3.2</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-205" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-205"><a href="">Button 3.3</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-207" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-207"><a class="menu-item-has-children">Button 3.4</a>
   
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-204"><a href="">Button 3.4.1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-203" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-203"><a href="">Button 3.4.2</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   </li>
  </ul>
  
 </li>
 
 <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="">Button 4</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103"><a href="">Button 5</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, I think that explains why it has been triggering twice. As soon as you mentioned it triggering for the 'li' and the 'a', it all made sense. Really appreciate your help and it made perfect sense. Thanks again!